# Can I delete *_local tables after upsizing the Access project to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I upsized an Access 2010 project (.accdb file) to SQL Server.  I only moved the tables and now the table list shows the linked tables and their local copies (e.g. tbl_local).

Can I delete these local tables or are they used for something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access is file based. Make a copy and delete the local files. They should not be needed, but if there is a problem, you can import from the copy. If you have Track Name Autocorrect turned on, there is a possibility some things may have been changed to use a renamed table.